# How to Properly Store Fertilizer?

Tags: fertilizer

I have a bag of granule lawn fertilizer (not weed and feed) that I am looking to store after having applied part of it to my lawn. What is the best way to store fertilizers, and how long can I store it before it goes bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some fertilizers are [hygroscopic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hygroscopic), perhaps even [deliquescent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deliquescent). In other words, they suck moisture out of the air and get soggy. Not all fertilizers do this, but you won't know until it happens, or not.
To prevent the possibility, you'll want to store in airtight containers.
20L paint buckets with lids work well.

Comment: I would say they are all hygroscopic , just to various degrees. And some may have volatile components  . So airtight is needed.

Comment: I keep them in the original (but open) bag or in a pail. I try to keep in a dry place, but ... in any case after some time it glue together. With some shot with a skydriver, it return normal. It is hard like glass, so when it break, it break overall (and in original grains). Try to keep far from mouses (you do not want a broken bag), and away burnable stuff.